# How to set class default props in react 18.2.0?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I saw some news about defaultProps being deprecated, but altenate solution I found was targeting function like component. But what about class component? I am new to react. Feeling like so many react things has change these years.

Oh I saw a another way is to use a deprecated package Prop-types, but it just don't feel right.

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ661.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the static defaultProps property

#### Typescript example

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyPropType,MyStateType> {

  static defaultProps = {
    /* Declare your default Props here */
  };
```

#### Javascript example

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // ...implement render method
  }
}

// Set default props
MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  /* Declare your default Props here */
};
```

Comment: Oh I just found that is TS causing my problem. Thanks anyway. xDDD

Answer (score 0):

yup, it will be deprecated in the future but only for functional components, for class-based components, it will stay as it is

Comment: Sorry I have tried it but it seems 'defaultProps' has removed. Bruno's solution works!

Comment: Oh I just found that TypeScript cause this problem, JS shoud be stay as same xDDD